# Is a subclass a new type?

Tags: swift, inheritance, types

If I subclass a class named `Animal` and name it `Dog`, is the class `Dog` a new type?

Comment: Let me ask you: what do you think "new type" means?

Comment: Formal academic definitions are a struggle for me. Um...the dog class has some common logic with the animal class, but it has a bit more to it so...it's different?

Comment: Is a dog an animal, yes. Is an animal a dog, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given these 2 definitions

```
class Animal { }
class Dog: Animal { }
```

well YES, `Animal` and `Dog` have different types and you can check it running this code

```
type(of: Animal()) == type(of: Dog())
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a nice answer here.  But for the records some additional thoughts:

In Swift, every class is a [named type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html):

> A named type is a type that can be given a particular name when it’s defined. Named types include classes, structures, enumerations, and protocols.

A subclass being a class, it's also a type. So `Dog` and `Animal` are two types.  The subclass `Dog` is a specialization of the more general `Animal`.  So a `Dog` can do everything that an `Animal` can do (maybe differently than other animals) and can do more:

```
class Animal {
    func reactToStranger() {
        print("Run away")
    }
    func sleep() {
        print ("zzzz")
    }
}
class Dog:Animal {
    override func reactToStranger() {  // do like an animal, but differently
        print("Bark ferocely", terminator:": ")
        bark()
    }
    func bark() {                     // only dog can do this
        print ("Ouaf Ouaf !!")
    }
}

let pet1 =  Animal() // type is Animal
let pet2 =  Dog()    // type is Dog which is a special kind of Animal
```

Since `Dog` is a special kind (subclass) of `Animal`,  it can be used everywhere where an `Animal` is expected. Let's try with our two pets:

```
func Test(_ pet: Animal) {
    print("Experiment with \(type(of: pet)) in presence of stranger", terminator:": ")
    pet.reactToStranger()
}

Test(pet1)    // pet1 is an Animal, so no surprise
Test(pet2)    // pet2 is a Dog, but it can be used as an Animal
pet2.bark()   // ok: pet2 is a Dog so it can also bark.
//pet1.bark() // not ok: pet1 is an Animal and animals in general do not bark. 
pet1.sleep()  // all animals can sleep
pet2.sleep()  // dog can sleep since it is a special kind of animal (inheritance)
```